# Why can't the Docker ("master") container see workers?

Tags: linux, docker, iptables

I'm running [Docker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_%28software%29) 1.7 and docker-compose 1.5.2 on [Oracle Enterprise Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Linux) (OEL) 6 with a 2.6 kernel.

I have adapted the CitusDB `docker-compose.yml` file in a few minor ways, except the main thing is that I only have one 'worker' entry and I use `docker-compose scale` to increase the numbers of workers. This works fine on the Docker 1.10/Docker-compose 2 configurations I was developing on, but these were using VirtualBox VMs under OS X/docker-machine.

Now to deploy on a regular native Linux box, I'm back-revved and the 'master' container cannot connect to the workers.

Port 5432 (standard PostgreSQL) is exposed, and each worker container has a different IP address, and they get put into [`/etc/hosts`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) on the master, but the master cannot connect to the workers.

I saw some messages about the firewall. The Linux box is using [iptables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables). When I start up using docker-compose, it creates an iptables DOCKER entry.

I tried disabling iptables and it did not change the results.

I tried creating alternative networks using the docker-compose `net:` directive and there was no difference.

Comment: This question could be improved by editing and adding in minimal, but complete, scripts, Dockerfiles, and/or .yml files for docker-compose that reproduce the problem.

Comment: @andrew-wolfe I'm assuming you're talking about Heap's [citus-docker repo](https://github.com/heap/citus-docker), which (as you note) uses the `/etc/hosts` file to generate the Citus worker list file. This feels more inline with the pre-v2 networking stack in Docker, and I'm wondering if maybe some of the changes you've made assume v2 networking features (added in Docker 1.9). Can you post your files (`docker-compose.yml`, `Dockerfile`, and any `COPY`'d files) here? I can't repro your issue otherwise.

Comment: Jason - we're concluding that our Oracle Linux and kernel versions are just falling down with docker 1.7 and docker-compose 1.6.  My boss has authorized provisioning a new (virtual) machine (where we can use the Docker hotness).  This config is rock-solid on VirtualBox and I also started testing on OEL 7 machines with no problems whatever.  I also configured an OEL 6 with kernel 4.1 and it just worked.  So we're moving on...

Comment: @AndrewWolfe — That's good information! Any interest in turning your comment into an answer for future readers, then marking your own answer as accepted? I think there's even a badge for answering your own question. I didn't know about this incompatibility, so I'm sure others would like the record for posterity.